# Getting textbox input in an SQLite database worked. But the second column doesn't work. How to fix this? (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sqlite, textbox

I'm working on a school project where people can test their own knowledge by typing words in the left column and typing their translation in the right column. This data has to be saved in a SQLite database.

So for example, a user types in the left textbox the word: **hello** and in the right textbox: **bonjour** (which is French for hello). Then I want to save the data into a SQLite database like this:

id: 1
word: hello
translation: bonjour

[image]

I managed to got it working with the following script:

```
string veld1 = txtVeld1.Text;
string veld1v2 = txtVeld1v2.Text;
string veld2 = txtVeld2.Text;
string veld2v2 = txtVeld2v2.Text;
string veld3 = txtVeld3.Text;
string veld3v2 = txtVeld3v2.Text;
string veld4 = txtVeld4.Text;
string veld4v2 = txtVeld4v2.Text;
string veld5 = txtVeld5.Text;
string veld5v2 = txtVeld5v2.Text;
string veld6 = txtVeld6.Text;
string veld6v2 = txtVeld6v2.Text;
conn.Open();

cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld1", veld1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld1v2", txtVeld1v2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld2", veld2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld2v2", txtVeld2v2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld3", veld3);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld3v2", txtVeld3v2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld4", veld4);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld4v2", txtVeld4v2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld5", veld5);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld5v2", txtVeld5v2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld6", veld6);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld6v2", txtVeld6v2);
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tboverhoren (woord, vertaling) SELECT @veld1 , @veld1v2 UNION ALL SELECT @veld2 , @veld2v2 UNION ALL SELECT @veld3 , @veld3v2 UNION ALL SELECT @veld4 , @veld4v2 UNION ALL SELECT @veld5 , @veld5v2 UNION ALL SELECT @veld6 , @veld6v2";
```

**(I'm using the UNION ALL SELECT statement because I want to insert multiple rows at once)**
But unfortunately only the first column does get the input from the textboxes. The second column only gets: "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox" as data.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I searched STACK overflow but only found that I have to declare the Textbox.Text function, which I did and worked with the first column. Other solutions I found didn't work with SQLite...

I really apreciate your help!

Kind regards,

Elias Groot

Comment: I'm not very used to SQLite but I think it should be `INSERT INTO tboverhoren SELECT @veld1 as woord , @veld1v2 as vertaling...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already extract the strings from the textboxes by accessing the Text property, for example:

```
string veld1v2 = txtVeld1v2.Text;
```

But then when you're actually them, you pass the textbox itself, rather than using the declared variable:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld1v2", txtVeld1v2);
```

The data framework sees that the textbox is not a type it understands, so calls `ToString()` on it, which by default returns the type name, which is why you see it in the database.

All you need to do is change those lines to use the variables:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veld1v2", veld1v2); // etc
```